# Testing Java Script app using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, extjs, jasmine

I have build an app using Sencha Architect and planning to test it using Jasmine. I am fairly new to Sencha Architect and Jasmine. In order for me to test the app, do I need to add the ExtJS Libraries/CSS in my HTML index file? I already add all the Jasmine frameworks CSS and JS files together with the Jasmine Test Case File in my HTML index file.

Thanks guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App folder is not loading in Ext.appliation when i try to test using jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923991/app-folder-is-not-loading-in-ext-appliation-when-i-try-to-test-using-jasmine)

Answer (score 1):

*I will guide you through a quick setup with working tests using Sencha Cmd 5.*, ExtJs 5.* and expecting you to use a Sencha workspace in just 8 steps.*

1. First create a new workspace using `Sencha Cmd`. If you already have a workspace you can skip this step.

   `sencha generate workspace \path\to\the\folder`
2. Create a new `ExtJs` app using `Sencha Cmd`.

   `cd \path\to\the\workspace
   sencha -sdk \path\to\the\sdk generate app Jasmine jasmine`
3. Then create a new folder called `app-test` within the app folder.
4. Download the standalone version of [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/releases)
5. Unzip it and copy the `lib` folder into the `app-test` folder you created before.
6. Create a html file `index-test.html` and place it in your app folder:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Jasmine Test</title>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="app-test/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="app-test/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">

 <script src="app-test/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
 <script src="app-test/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
 <script src="app-test/lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>

 <!-- include source files here... -->
 <script src="../ext/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

 <!-- include spec files here... -->
 <script src="app-test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

7. Create a javascript file `app-test.js` and place it in your app folder:

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
 name: 'Jasmine',
 extend: 'Jasmine.Application',
 autoCreateViewport: false
});

describe('Jasmine.view.main.Main', function() {
 //reusable scoped variable
 var mainView = null;

 // setup / teardown
 beforeEach(function() {
  // create a fresh main view for every test to avoid test pollution
  mainView = Ext.create('Jasmine.view.main.Main'/*, {
   renderTo : 'test' //see index-test.html to see where this is defined
  }*/);
 });

 afterEach(function() {
  // destroy the main view after every test so we don't pollute the environment
  mainView.destroy();
 });

 it('should inherit from Ext.container.Container', function() {
  expect(mainView.isXType('container')).toEqual(true);
 });

 it('should be configured as a border layout', function() {
  expect(mainView.getLayout().type).toEqual('border');
 });
});
```

8. Open index-test.html in a browser and see the results

*Extra resources:*
http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/setup-jasmine-tdd-with-for-ext-js/
https://www.sencha.com/blog/automating-unit-tests/
https://github.com/SenchaProSvcs/UnitTestDemo
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/testing
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/testing_controllers
https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html